# How do I change screen resolution in Fedora 15?

Tags: x-windows, resolution, fedora-15

I installed Fedora 15 recently and am struggling to find a way to set screen resolution to greater than 1280x800. Has anybody tried doing this?

Comment: wha'ts the problem?

Comment: Here is what tried                             [root@dev bin]# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 190mm
   1280x800       60.0*+   50.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      59.9  
DVI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
[root@dev bin]# xrandr -s 1920*1080
Size index 1920 is too large, there are only 4 sizes

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong syntax - the command you wanted is `xrandr -s 1920x1280`. Note the 'x' character between the dimensions, not the '*' character that you used.

Comment: this is what I get now.                                            [root@dev bin]# xrandr -s 1640x1040
Size 1640x1040 not found in available modes

Comment: [NOT SOLVED]: The error is "Size 1920x1280 not found in available modes". I have the same problem too, using Fedora 15, i get also this error to go higher then the default maximum value i had.